# Latency in mp3 live streaming on Google home assistant

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I’m trying to play mp3 live streaming and I’m using “media response” as shown in the Action on Google guide, here is the code:

```
if(!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO')) {
  conv.ask('Sorry, this device does not support audio playback.');
}
else{
  conv.ask(new MediaObject({
    name: 'Radio one',
    url: 'my_streaming_url.mp3',
    description: 'A funky Jazz tune',
  }));
  conv.ask(new Suggestions(['Radio two']));
}
```

All works fine, but there is about 20 seconds of audio latency on Google home and Google home mini. No latency on Google Assistant Android app and on Action on Google Simulator and no latency also if “url” is an mp3 file. Any idea why there is this delay?

Answer (score 2):

Google Home's media player appears to buffer roughly 20-30 seconds of playable audio before starting.

If you control the Icecast streaming server, increase the `<burst-size>` value either in the `<limits />` section or `<mount />`. By default, it is set to 65536 bytes.

You can work out the ideal burst-size limit for your stream in bytes by calculating the following:

`bitrateKbps * bufferSeconds * 1024 / 8`

For a 128kbps stream, try 327680.

(Also, make sure the server's `<queue-size />` is bigger than the burst-size)

Answer (score 0):

The 20 second latency with live streaming urls appears to be a thing on google home (mini) and chromecast.  Not only if initiated from google assistant : also when using google cast API.  I have no idea why they use so much buffering.